# Wordpress custom post-type url have separate url from blog posts

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, custom-post-type

I've created a custom post-type in my theme, named portfolio. I've set the permalinks for my blog to be `/blog/post-name`, and now by default my portfolio posts are `/blog/portfolio/post-name` is there any way to take the blog part out of the portfolio url?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be using [WP_Rewrite](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite) but there is no way of overriding the base path (`/blog`) as it's the `RewriteBase /blog/` rule in the generated `.htaccess` file.
So either remove that base path and use `WP_Rewrite` to add it back or manually edit `.htaccess` and rewrite it, before the `RewriteBase` directive:

```
...
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/blog/portfolio/(.*)$ http://example.com/portfolio/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteBase /blog/
...
```

But I would not encourage this as WordPress *will* overwrite your changes the next time you submit the permalinks admin form.

So long story short: remove that `/blog/` basepath. If you don't know how to use `WP_Rewrite` then you could register a new custom post type named "Blog Post" with `blog` for the `slug` parameter and use those instead of the default "Posts".